# Vuejs as an HTML templating engine

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm looking for a front-end HTML templating engine and I was wondering if Vuejs has this functionally built into it. If not, can someone recommend me a templating engine?

All I want to do is create HTML pages which derived from a master page.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that vue js need a template engine. You can use any pre processors like jade or other for html if you use vueify or vue-loader

Answer (score 1):

I've used Mustache and have found it great - easy to use and fast. Check it out here: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/